# how to stop jodit from removing font awesome tags?

Tags: jodit

When I toggle in and out of source mode, jodit removes this font awesome code:

`<i class="fa-li fa fa-check-circle"></i>`

On the first toggle out and toggle into source mode, Jodit changes it to 'em'.

On the 2nd toggle in + out, the code just totally disappears. How do I get Jodit to stop doing that?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by simply disabling cleanHTML plugin altogether.

`cleanHTML: false`.